# Problems with Program startup in WIn 7 this week

Tags: windows-7

I have a program (ISYS) that I have been using since 2006.  It migrated successfully to Windows 7.  Just yesterday it started manifesting this strange behavior.  The program has a selector to allow you to select a directory that might have relevant files for the program.  As of yesterday the program will only let me select folders on the C drive.  For example I have a folder on D that I need to access with this program - from the GUI when I select the D drive the directory list does not load, instead it churns away using 17% of the CPU cycles.  I have let it run for an hour several times.

I have found that I can get the directory I want by using a batch file to start the program but this limits my ability to do certain things I really need to use the GUI.

I did a number of reboots and other tests - I disconnected drives but once I try to select some directory on a drive other than C it churns away.

I have experimented quite a bit and am convinced (which means I am wrong) that this has something to do with some setting change on my computer that I can't figure out as I don't see any updates.

Since ISYS has not been updated I feel confident it is something internal.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Some time later

This is really interesting - I got a new drive - formatted it and installed it in my computer.  (Note I added it I did not replace an existing drive) I then tried to use the GUI and selected the new drive and was able to do everything I needed to do.  It meant I had to copy files from other drives to the new drive but still I had no problems once I did this.

I left the computer on overnight and came back this morning and now I have the same problem with that new drive I installed.  So something happened to the drive.  Specifically once I select the drive the program goes to cycling -  **something is happening to the drive** .

Not sure if I should post this as an answer or just here until someone who really understands what is going on pipes in so they can get the credit.  Since I noticed the behavior I took off the two zip files that I had created using 7.zip on another computer and copied on the drive.  When I moved the files into a folder on the computer the program acted as expected.  Then if I moved one or the other out of the folder the program would hang.  Clearly the program was trying to read the files and was not able to for one reason or another.  Thus when the 7-ZIP files were at the root of the drive the program hung - so because I am dependent on this particular software I have to be careful not to have any unknown file types at the root of a drive I need to operate on or in a folder I need to operate on.

Comment: Have you tried going back to a System Restore point from before the problem started?  Have you tried reinstalling the program?

Comment: Am I smart enough to have set up a system restore point ?  Of course not